# How to use or get multiple intent actions from same Broadcast Receiver class

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two intent actions in a single receiver class. In manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"></action>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

And in receiver class inside `onReceive()`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("--------BOOT-----------"+intent.getAction());
}
```

Here `intent.getAction()` returns only "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" but I am not able to track "Boot Completed" action. Is there anyway to get multiple intent actions from a common `onReceive()`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get multiple broadcasts delivered to a single `onReceive()`. Make sure you have the permission

```
 <uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

in your manifest.

Also, as of Android 3.1 you won't get the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast unless your application has been run by the user at least once. See http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html